# A word meaning something familiar but which you can't put the right name to?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

So I want a word that means familiar but which you can't put the right name to.  The context is I have discovered a tune on Youtube which I have heard many times (probably used for an advert) but I did not know name of.

So here is a link which illustrates what I'm talking about.

[21 Songs You've Totally Heard, But Never Knew The Names Of](https://www.buzzfeed.com/jessicamisener/songs-youve-totally-heard-but-never-knew-the-names-of?utm_term=.efxrNrOV2a#.cnxe5e07XD)

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would like to use this word?  What unsatisfactory sentences have you thought of?

Comment: @Kevin Mark: actually I was trying to name a Youtube playlist and I was unhappy with 3 words.  This is a plain single word request and I have edited question to be tagged as such.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to (1) demonstrate how you would use the word, (2) note what qualities you're looking for in the word (e.g. formal or informal), and (3) say which words you've considered and why you rejected them. This would help us focus on the range of words that are of greater interest to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a single word to label a playlist of songs which are familiar but which you can't *place.*   Below is the Macmillan English Dictionary entry for one meaning of the verb "place."

I think the word you are looking for is ***Unplaced.***

[image]

Comment: Oh, you beauty!   I was getting there with a thesaurus, unacknowledged was pretty close.  unplaced is perfect.

Comment: Glad you like it!  It was fun teasing it out of you.

Comment: Actually, unintroduced comes close as well.